# Accidentally change repository remove all my files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift2

I just changed my repository from branch to another, It is giving me a message that will recreate, and i clicked yes. Suddenly all my Xcode files disappeared, now i have only two files. !!
How can i retrieve it again? I am new in mac. I searched for ctrl + z or any thing retrive my files.

Comment: try to switch back to previous repository, your files must be in local revision.

Comment: its wok thank you so much